# Isomorphism of lattices/complex tori

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, modular-group

This is essentially a reference request (apologies if it is a duplicate): it is known that every lattice $\Lambda$ in $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic to one of the form $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}[\tau]$ for some $\tau \in \mathbb{H}$, the upper half-plane. Let $\Lambda_1 = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}[\tau_1]$, $\Lambda_2 = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}[\tau_2]$

It can be shown that $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_1 \cong \mathbb{C}/\Lambda_2$ if and only if there exists $\gamma \in \text{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$ such that $\tau_1 = A \cdot \tau_2$. Can someone point me to a resource which contains a full proof of this result? Thank you.

Comment: Just as a note: every lattice isomorphic to one of the form $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \tau$, not $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}[\tau]$. $\mathbb{Z}[\tau]$ is often not discrete and typically the lattice won't contain $\tau^2, \tau^3, \ldots$.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked out the details: proof below.

We use the fact that $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda_1 \cong \mathbb{C}/\Lambda_2$ if and only if $\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2$ are homothetic, *i.e.* there exists $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}^{*}$ such that $\Lambda_1 = \alpha \Lambda_2$. Due to this, an arbitrary lattice generated by $\langle \omega_1, \omega_2 \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\langle 1, \omega_1/\omega_2 \rangle$. Then without loss of generality we can take $\Lambda_1 = \langle 1, \tau_1 \rangle$ for $\tau_1 \in \mathbb{H}$ and similarly for $\Lambda_2$.

The group $\text{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$ acts on $\mathbb{H}$ via fractional linear transformations: $$\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\\ \end{pmatrix} \in \text{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$$ acts via
$$\gamma \cdot \tau = \dfrac{a \tau + b}{c \tau + d}$$
and we can compute that
$$\text{Im}(\gamma \cdot \tau) = \dfrac{\text{det}(\gamma)}{|c \tau + d|^2} \text{Im}(\tau)$$

Now we show that $\Lambda_1 \cong \Lambda_2$ if and only if there exists $\gamma \in \text{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$ such that $\tau_2 = \gamma \cdot \tau_1$.

Suppose $\tau_2 = \gamma \cdot \tau_1$ for some $\gamma$. Then $\Lambda_2 = \langle a\tau_1 + b, c\tau_1 + d \rangle$, but since $ad - bc = 1$ this is the same lattice as $\langle 1, \tau_1 \rangle = \Lambda_1$.

Conversely, suppose $\Lambda_1 = \alpha \Lambda_2$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$. On generators this means $\langle \alpha, \alpha \tau_2 \rangle = \langle 1, \tau_1 \rangle.$ In this case
$$\alpha = c \tau_1 + d$$
$$\alpha \tau_2 = a \tau_1 + b$$
for some $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Similarly, there exist $e, f, g, h \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$\tau_1 = e(a \tau_1 + b) + f(c \tau_1 + d)$$
$$1 = g(a \tau_1 + b) + h(c \tau_1 + d)$$
Since $1, \tau_1$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-linearly independent, we can rephrase this as
$$\begin{pmatrix} e & f\\ g & h\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 1\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Taking determinants yields $\text{det}(\gamma) \in \{\pm 1\}$, but
$$\text{Im}(\tau_2) = \text{Im}\dfrac{a \tau_1 + b}{c \tau_1 + d} = \dfrac{\text{det}(\gamma)}{|c \tau + d|^2} \text{Im}(\tau_1)$$
and since $\tau_1, \tau_2 \in \mathbb{H}$, we have $\text{Im}(\tau_1), \text{Im}(\tau_2) > 0$, and so $\text{det}(\gamma) = 1$. Therefore, such a $\gamma$ exists in $\text{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$, and we are done.

As a consequence, we can identify the space of isomorphism classes of complex tori with the quotient $\mathbb{H} \backslash \text{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$, or in other words, the modular curve $Y(1)$, whose points can be identified with the fundamental domain for the $\text{SL}(2, \mathbb{Z})$-action on the upper half-plane:
$$\mathcal{F} = \{\tau \in \mathbb{H} \mid |\text{Re}(\tau)| \leq 1/2, |\tau| \geq 1\}$$

Comment: What do you mean by $\text{Im(z)}$? Other than that, your proof seems correct at a skim.

Comment: Thanks for the catch - meant to write $\text{Im}(\gamma \cdot \tau)$ here; fixed.

Comment: If you're looking for existing sources, I know Forster has it from the complex viewpoint, and there are numerous sources approaching it from the mapping class group viewpoint (I most recently saw it in Martelli's book on geometric toplogy). I imagine Miranda's book would also have a proof, though I've only skimmed that text so can't confirm. I can't think of a text off the top of my head that does it from the analytic/conformal standpoint... Maybe Hubbard's book on Teichmuller Theory would have it?